# Double quotes in a string C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to read through a file and look for this tag 
    ,`<table name="File">`,
i've read a bunch and everyone tells me to use `@"""` or `\"` to accept the double quotes in the middle of the string, but what it does is turns my string into this. `<table name=\"File\">` and it still doesn't work because thats not how it is in the file. examples:

```
string tblName = "  <table name="+@"""File"""+">";
string tblName = "  <table name=\"File\">";
```

Nothing seems to work. It just addes the \ into the string and i can't replace it because it removes the quotes. Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
 string tblName = "  <table name="+@"""File"""+">";


         try 
    {
        // Only get files that begin with the letter "c."
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\dylan.stewart\Desktop\Testing\", "*.ism");
        //Console.WriteLine("The number of files starting with c is {0}.", dirs.Length);
        foreach (string dir in dirs) 
        {
            foreach( string line in File.ReadLines(dir))
            if(line.Contains(tblName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir);
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(dir);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Place the @ at the beginning of the string to make it literal.  string tblName = @"  <table name="File">";

Comment: The second one should work fine. -edit- the first one too, although it looks a bit awkward. If it doesn't work, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: How are you using `tblName` to seach for this string?

Comment: i've tried @ in front it does the same thing adding the \

Comment: @dstew it does not add the `\ `, it just shows it in the debugger

Comment: @JohnCarpenter  foreach( string line in File.ReadLines(dir))if(line.Contains(tblName))

Comment: Can you post more code so we can actually see how you use it ?

Comment: You can also use `'"'` which is a `char`: "  `<table name=" + '"' + "File" + '"' + ">";`

Comment: @Wimmel can you please show me how you are typing it in. For some reason no matter how i do it it addes the \ into the string

Comment: @WaiHaLee You can, but it won't solve the problem.

Comment: @dstew are you sure about spaces at the beginning of `"  <table name="+@"""File"""+">";` ?

Comment: The debugger probably shows the `\`s in there, but they are not really there. If they don't match the file, maybe the value that is read from the file is slightly different, for instance having a space at the end of the line or so.

Comment: @tchelidze that's a good thought. Make sure you do a .trim() to remove whitespace before and after the string literal.

Comment: @dstew Regex may be more safe in this scenario, please provide file content. there may be some extra white space or something that causes not matching.

Comment: Another shot in the dark, but if you should match any amount of whitespace around or within you tag, then you should be using a regular expression

Comment: @dstew Try following in `if statement`  `Regex.IsMatch(line, @".*\<table\s+name\s*=\s*\"\s*File\s*\"\s*+\s*\>.*")`

Comment: Like tchelidze said, the spaces probably don't belong there. If the original file contains tabs, you will not find the search string.

Comment: You guys are correct. I don't need to look for the white space! Sorry! Thanks for stumbling through this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above methods for adding " into a string are correct. The issue with my OP is i was searching for a specific amount of white space before the tag. I removed the spaces and used the mentioned methods and it is now working properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you should mark your answer as accepted by checking the mark since you solved the problem you had.

Answer (score 0):

```
string tblName = "<table name=" + '"' + "File" + '"' + ">";
```

should work since the plus sign concatenate

Answer (score -1):

It should be either

```
string tblName = @" <table name=""File"">";
```

or

```
string tblName = "  <table name=\"File\">";
```

No need for concatenation. Also what do you mean "it still doesn't work"? Just try `Console.Write()` and you'll see it ok. If you mean the backslashes are visible while inspecting in debugger then it's supposed to be that way
B

Comment: The second one is what OP already tried. The first one is cleaner, but essentially the same as OPs first one. So this answer doesn't help in solving the problem.

Comment: when you look in the debugger it says " <table name=\"File\">" and wont find it in the file.

Comment: @dstew That's just how the debugger displays double quotes in a string, by delimiting them with a backslash, but the backslash is not actually in the string.